# Poisson Modeling ANOVA

Tags: r, regression, anova, poisson-regression, mean

I'm looking to model percent change in transaction year over year for sales people grouped in certain categories (7 categories total). The percent change in transactions would be Q1 of the current year divided by the number of transactions from Q1 of the previous year which gives me a percent change (positive or negative).

Since this is count data the correct model to use is the Poisson distribution and eventually I would like to do a Poisson regression to look at the effects of predictor variables on percent change in transactions.

But my question is, if I want to compare the means between the different groups what is the analogous version of the ANOVA for Poisson assumptions. (if that's the correct way to put it)

Comment: Would you mind clarifying a little bit what the data look like and what the question is? You have the performance of sales people grouped by region over 2 years? You would like to measure the percent change from year to year in each region, as well as compare each region to the others?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP has not responded to requests and it has been years.